# Heyzap Video Ad. Cordova. Не могу получить видео по тегу дефолт

Tags: cordova

Добрый!

Пытаюсь встроить показ рекламы в приложение. Вставляю код из гайда:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {

    HeyzapAds.start("мой ключ").then(function() {
        // Native call successful.

        // Start fetching ads
        HeyzapAds.InterstitialAd.show().then(function() {


        }, function(error) {
            // Handle Error
        });

    return HeyzapAds.showMediationTestSuite();

    }, function(error) {

        // Handle Error
    });

}, false);
```

Далее при старте открывается окно с аддонами:
[image]

Далее захожу в Heyzap и вижу следующую ошибку:
[image]

Подскажите, проблема в коде или в настройках аккаунта Heyzap, а точнее в списке видео по тегу дефолт?

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось что я не привязал приложение в настройках Хейзап аккаунта.
https://developers.heyzap.com/account/edit_apps

[image]